# Is there any opensource Memory DISK Buffer implementation in java?

Tags: java, memory, buffer, disk

I don't know how to name this kind of buffer exactly, I need it in the following scenario:

1. Data are received continuously from network.
2. The data received are added into Buffer.
3. There is a reader reading data from Buffer continuously and perform processing actions.

Since the data is big and can not be totally resident in memory.I need a buffer that can manage the exchange between memory and disk(flushing data to disk if buffer is full and reading data from memory buffer or disk continuously), which is transparent to writer and reader(much like a database but I want to keep it fast,simple and light weight).
Don't know if there is any opensource implementation for it..
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Comment: Hi sjr. Actually I just want to write and read in sequence instead of key/value style..